# Certbot - Failed authorization procedure

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I want to generate a Let's Encrypt certificate for my server, so that I can renew it automatically.
I ran the command `certbot --nginx -d testpbx.info.eu` and got the following error.

```
certbot --nginx -d testpbx.info.eu
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Please read the Terms of Service at
https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf. You must
agree in order to register with the ACME server at
https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
(A)gree/(C)ancel: a

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Would you be willing to share your email address with the Electronic Frontier
Foundation, a founding partner of the Let's Encrypt project and the non-profit
organization that develops Certbot? We'd like to send you email about our work
encrypting the web, EFF news, campaigns, and ways to support digital freedom.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
(Y)es/(N)o: n
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for testpbx.info.eu
Using default addresses 80 and [::]:80 ipv6only=on for authentication.
nginx: [warn] duplicate network "::0/0", value: "0", old value: "1" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/3cxpbx:14
nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/var/lib/3cxpbx/Bin/nginx/conf/Instance1/testpbx.info.eu-crt.pem"
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
nginx: [warn] duplicate network "::0/0", value: "0", old value: "1" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/3cxpbx:14
nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/var/lib/3cxpbx/Bin/nginx/conf/Instance1/testpbx.info.eu-crt.pem"
Failed authorization procedure. testpbx.info.eu (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: 185.203.28.51: Fetching http://testpbx.info.eu/.well-known/acme-challenge/82VDIjmjQpI-ljtnkFsT8HpUvLytub6Obb7ox5GAzOg: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: testpbx.info.eu
   Type:   connection
   Detail: 185.xxx.xx.xx: Fetching
   http://testpbx.info.eu/.well-known/acme-challenge/82VDIjmjQpI-ljtnkFsT8HpUvLytub6Obb7:
   Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
 - Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot
   configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a
   secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will
   also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so
   making regular backups of this folder is ideal.
```

I would like to point out that my domain name is entered correctly and that the A DNS record for this domain contain the correct IP address.
contain the correct IP address, I also `ping 8.8.8.8.`

Answer (score 1):

Is your server accesible for external observers? Try `curl http://testpbx.info.eu`. If that fails, it is likely blocked by firewall, you'll need to open port 80 on your servers. How to do it depends on your operating system as different firewalls are present on different systems.

Comment: If you're are unable to offer port 80 then differerent challenge types are available, such as [DNS](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge), but it will need to be configured manually.